# PHP: exporting mysql database into CSV based on 2 columns?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a users table in mysql database and each user has a `referral_code` column and a `referral_code_used` column.

The `referral_code` holds the users referral code that they can share with others.

The `referral_code_used` holds the referral code that the user's received from another user and they have entered during the signup.

Example:

```
user   referral_code    referral_code_used        email

A         TW89                                email@email.com
---------------------------------------------------------------
B         TW66               TW89            email2@email.com
```

In the example above, the user B has used the user A `referral_code`.

Now, what i need to do is to export this data into a CSV file and the CSV file should look like this (sort of):

```
referrer                   referred         

email@email.com         email2@email.com
```

that's it.

so far I can export the entire mysql as CSV file using the following code but I can't figure out how to do what I am trying to do and I don't know if it is possible:

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    $rows = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM `users`');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {


      fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
    mysqli_close($db_conx);
    exit();

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I tried this and this will generate an empty CSV file:

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    $rows = mysqli_query($db_conx, 'SELECT u.email as referrer, ref.email as referred from users u INNER JOIN users ref on u.ref_code=ref.ref_code_used');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {


      fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
    mysqli_close($db_conx);
    exit();

?>
```

and I don't see any errors at all!

Comment: to debug export csv file try to use ob_clean() at the start of file and use error_reporting(E_ALL), and make sure your sql query is working

Comment: you have u.ref_code=ref.ref_code_used and, according to your DB, should be u. referral_code =ref. referral_code_used 

Could that be it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work - the concept you're looking for is inner-joining the table to itself in order to match different rows to each other, based on the referral codes:

```
select 
  A.email as 'referrer', 
  B.email as 'referred'
from 
  users A
  inner join users B
    on A.referral_code = B.referral_code_used
```

Comment: This also generate an empty CSV file!

Comment: test the query separately first (e.g. in mysql workbench) before trying to create the CSV file. Perhaps you didn't give us an accurate description of the data structure or contents.

Comment: I just kept everything as minimal a possible. obviously the MYSQL table has more columns but it was not necessary to mention them in my question.

Comment: That's fine in itself, but the query I've written works against your sample data. See a live example at http://rextester.com/YWOGHC64815 (I had to rename the table to get it to work in that environment, but other than that it's the same). So either the sample data is not truly representative of your data structure, or you simply don't have any matching data in your database, or there's something else significant you're not telling us. But as far as I can see, I've answered the question as it was asked, with a working query.

Comment: Oops, there is no user A, B in my mysql database. I just used that in my question to explain the situation!

Comment: well that particular thing itself shouldn't matter. The query doesn't use or need the `user` column, or take any account of the values within it. But there need to be some users who have matching referral codes in those columns, otherwise yes you'll get an empty result set.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case where you have to make a join on the same table. I imagine something like this:

```
Select u.email as referrer, ref.email as referred from users u 
INNER JOIN users ref on u.referral_code=ref.referral_code_used
```